# Apache port issues

Tags: windows, apache, xampp, port

I have installed XAMPP for Windows 7 and get this error:

*port 80 or 443 (ssl) already in use installing apache2.2 service failed*

Where can I see what programa uses these ports?

I already have make check my Skype settings and disabled use of ports 80 and 443 as alternative, but the ports is still used.

Also I have installed:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
- MS SQL Management Studio

may be due to these problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `netstat` command to find out that.

The BSD netstat is available as part of Windows.  Open `cmd.exe` and type `netstat -an`.

The command help is available from this page:
http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netstat.mspx?mfr=true

HTH.

Comment: Specifically, use netstat -anb to see the associated processes.